# How to connect to TOR server from other computers

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to install `tor` server on `TorServer` computer and I like to use it on other machine in the network.

For example, in TorServer I can do

```
curl --socks5 localhost:9050 somewebsite.com
```

I like to do something like this on otherComputer

```
curl --socks5 TorServer:9050 somewebsite.com
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I'm not 100% on this but I think 9050 is designed to only be accessible to localhost, so TorServer is refusing requests incoming to 9050.

If that's the case you'll need a proxy on TorServer to forward incoming requests to 9050.

I've used Privox before and that's worked well.

Comment: ahh, lol why didn't I think of that huh... very useful thank you